# Can I use cimport inside a Cython pxd file?

Tags: cython

I want to use the uint_fast16_t type in a Cython function. Can I gain access to it in my pxd file by adding `from libc.stdint cimport uint_fast16_t` to the top of the file? I've searched the Cython documentation and I can't find any mention of using `cimport` inside a pxd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It seems that adding a cimport line to the top of my pxd file does work. Here is a small test case I've used to demonstrate:

**test.pxd:**

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint_fast16_t

cdef uint_fast16_t double_it(uint_fast16_t x)
```

**test.pyx:**

```
# cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, cdivision=True
from test cimport double_it, uint_fast16_t

cdef uint_fast16_t double_it(uint_fast16_t x):
    return 2*x

def fast_double(uint_fast16_t x):
    return double_it(x)
```

Result after `cythonize-3.7 -i test.pyx && python`

```
>>> import test
>>> test.fast_double(10)
20
```

The compiler directives I put at the top of `test.pyx` were copied from my main project file. I put it there simply to make sure it worked using the same exact settings I was already using. I don't think any of them are necessary to use `cimport` inside a `.pxd` file.